# list by nearest using latlng

Tags: java, android

It seems to list according to location but it isn't using my location instead listing from the highest point of South Africa(Polokwane) to the lowest(Cape Town). I have tried changing my location many times and it makes no difference to the results.

```
LatLng myLoc;

public DistanceArrange(LatLng current)
{
    myLoc = current;
}
@Override
public int compare(final Sites sites, final Sites sites1) 
{
    double lat = MapsActivity.DMStoDD(MapsActivity.removeLastChar(sites.getLatitude()));
    double lon = MapsActivity.DMStoDD(MapsActivity.removeLastChar(sites.getLongitude()));
    double lat1 = MapsActivity.DMStoDD(MapsActivity.removeLastChar(sites1.getLatitude()));
    double lon1 =  MapsActivity.DMStoDD(MapsActivity.removeLastChar(sites1.getLongitude()));

    double distance = computeDistanceBetween(myLoc, new LatLng(lat, lon));
    double distance1 = computeDistanceBetween(myLoc, new LatLng(lat1, lon1));

    return (int)(distance  - distance1 );
}
```

The DMStoDD is a conversion function of my own which works fine because I'm currently plotting all of these points on the map

Comment: you should return -1, 0, or 1, not the difference of the distances

Comment: What's in computeDistanceBetween()?

Comment: ComputeDistanceBetween is a google Geometry Library function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it is ok to have distance1-distance2, order of list is decided using whether (distance1-distance2) is equal to negative value or  positive value

May be distance computed is incorrect. You can use class [android.location.Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html),it has method [distanceTo()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceTo(android.location.Location)) like this.

```
double distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(targetLocation)
```

Sample snippet:

```
public int compare(final ThinResult task1, final ThinResult task2) {
        Location location1 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Location location2 = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        location1.setLatitude(task1.getLatitude());
        location1.setLongitude(task1.getLongitude());
        location2.setLatitude(task2.getLatitude());
        location2.setLongitude(task2.getLongitude());

        double distanceToPlace1 = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(location1);
        double distanceToPlace2 = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(location2);
        return (int) (distanceToPlace1 - distanceToPlace2);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is that by casting to int, you're rounding down most* results to zero.

You should return -1 or 1, depending on which of distance or distance1 is the greatest.

*assuming you're using radians

Comment: So I just tried that and it just listed them visa versa. return (distance > distance1 ? -1 : 1 ); for some reason it doesn't seem to be using my location